# Printing hash contents with a line counter in Ruby

Tags: ruby, loops, hash

first of all let me tell you that I've searched Google, StackOverflow and even books like the Ruby Cookbook, etc. and still I couldn't find any solution for this simple problem:

```
myhash = Hash.new 0

myhash["wood"] = "any string"
myhash["palm"] = "any other string"
myhash["pine"] = "any thing"

myhash.each do |key, value|
  puts "#{key}: #{value}"
end
```

I'd like to have an output like this:

```
1- wood: any string 
2- palm: any other string 
3- pine: any thing
```

i.e. a number (which I call "line counter") must be at the beginning of each line . I don't know how to add it into the iteration, how can I do it? Note: That must be done without using any gems. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `each_with_index` for this. However, you need to be sure and designate the key and value into a group with parentheses.

```
myhash.each_with_index do |(key, value), index|   # <-- Notice the group of (key, val)
  puts "#{index} - #{key}: #{value}"
end
```

The reason you're required to group the key and value in parentheses is because the `each_with_index` method takes only produces variables to the block loop; normally the `value` and `index`. Therefore, you need to deconstruct the first element (key and value) explicitly.

For contrast, a normal array would use the method simply as

```
array.each_with_index do |val, index|
```

Comment: Or if you use `each.with_index(1)` instead of `each_with_index` then you don't need to do the interpolation addition.

Comment: Hello thank you the answer and the comments solved the issue. But I'd like to know why (key, value) is grouped together. That particular usage is not evident in Ruby tutorials and books or let me say I don't remember seeing such a usage. Thanks.